# Compress a dir into many small tar and uncompress it back to same parent directory

Tags: unix, tar, compression

I have huge(90GB) directory which i want to compress into multiple .tgz files in a way that, when i untar all these small .tgz files they all uncompress to same main directory.

For eg:

```
Parent_dir/1-1000000files
```

Compress it to multiple small `subset1.tgz subset2.tgz subset3.tgz` etc.

Now hen i uncompress they all should expand to same `Parent_dir`.

I have used `tar czvf name/of/tar files/to/compress`

How can i achieve this ..?

Comment: Do you really want to have multiple .tgz ? Or splitting the huge .tgz will be sufficient ?

Comment: This is a Unix utility question, not a programming question. Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/